# Unknown error when trying to append to feature layer with ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-python-api

I am trying to perform an 'upsert' (UPDATE + INSER) operation on a feature layer via ArcGIS API for Python. My input data is a GeoJSON file that gets uploaded as per the available [guides](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/appending-features/#add-the-source-csv-item-to-the-gis):

```
data_item = gis.content.add(
    item_properties={
        'title': 'My Data File',
        'type': 'GeoJson',  
        'overwrite': True,
    },
    data="myfile.geojson"
)
Then I attempt the append operation:

my_layer.append(
    item_id=data_item.id,
    upload_format='geojson', 
    upsert=True,
    upsert_matching_field='an_unique_field',
    update_geometry=True,
)
```

This returns Exception:

> Unknown Error (Error Code: 500).

The GeoJSON file is valid (checked in geojson.io). Attempts with a smaller file (original has ~4000 polygons) or appending a featureCollection instead of GeoJSON fail with the same error. Manually updating the data via ArcGIS online works fine with the exact same file. Any leads here?

I have successfully performed the operation using [edit_features()](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.edit_features) instead of [append()](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.append) but it requires querying the layer, mapping OBJECTIDs to an_unique_field, creating separate adds and updates collections, then splitting the collections into 250 features chunks. I'd like to skip all this with a single append call if possible.